# how does pusher count connections for pricing?

Tags: pusher

If a pusher client connects to multiple channels is that still considered one client connection?  Is the connection created and counted as soon as you new up  a pusher client object or only when the subscribe to a channel action occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is recorded as soon as you instantiate the Pusher object. The number of subscriptions to channels does not affect the number of connections.

See [this FAQ](https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019428173-How-are-connections-counted-) for more information.